# Mi base de datos desplegada en Azure y es muy lenta

Tags: azure

Mi base de datos desplegada en Azure, tengo 50 DTU, 14 usuarios y a pesar de eso es muy lenta, ¿Por lo que me pregunto qué podría afectar este rendimiento en mi base de datos y cómo podría mejorarla?

Esto lo he comprobado entrando al servidor cuando nadie está conectado e intento abrir SQL Server Management y el tiempo de respuesta al conectarme a la base de datos de Azure es muy lenta. Además he intentado habilitar algunas opciones de seguridad y active directory. Al igual utilizar una conexión de red de redirección.

Comment: Eso tiene que ver mucho con la configuración interna de la infraestructura y cómo está supuesta a escalar la base de datos para soportar la carga, además de dónde está ubicado el servidor y la latencia de la red, ya que esto afecta directamente al tiempo de respuesta, además de la complejidad. Personalmente, **usé Azure hace un tiempo y el servicio de base de base de datos es extremadamente lento**, ahora uso MongoDB Atlas, porque mi aplicación usa MongoDB y porque bajo la misma carga, Azure respondía después de 2 segundos y Atlas en 8ms, pero esto puede depender de las necesidades de tu app.

Comment: Si tienes una base de datos en Azure (o a mi entender, en cualquier nube) la latencia hará que los tiempos de respuestas sean lentos, las bases de datos en la nube funcionan para aplicaciones web (porque físicamente están cerca), para el caso de las aplicaciones cliente-servidor se deben virtualizar la aplicación a través de AVD u otra solución de virtualización. Si puedes suministrar más detalles de tu arquitectura, locaciones de premisa y azure pudiera darte una solución más especifica.